# HTaccess issue in joomla on my localhost

Tags: .htaccess, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla1.5

I've copied my live website to my localhost for migrating into higher version. The problem that has been arises is that my menus and components are not opening and it's saying that it does not found any articles and components that has been assigned to menu. So i just want to know that if i will upgrade my joomla website which is currently has 1.5.26 version to 2.5 then will it effect on my website when i will upload it later on after migrating into higher version. Will everything will gonna work fine or still having a htaccess issues or not?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that mod_rewrite is enabled in you Apache config.

What errors do you get - a 500 ?

Comment: I'm having an error which is The requested URL /mysite/muhurt-a-pachang was not found on this server

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee it will work after the upgrade. You need to get it working on the local site before upgrading in my opinion.

Try disabling SEF urls and see if the site starts working. If it does then you know that it is an .htaccess issue and you should be OK to upgrade and upload.

Comment: I've disabled my sef urls and still it's giving me the same error that it does not found the requested url. So is it a htaccess issue or something else?